# Why can't a norm be induced by a metric?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Given a normed linear space $M$, we can define a metric as $d(x,y) = \left\lVert x-y \right\rVert$, but given a metric $d$, can't we define a norm as: $\left\lVert x \right\rVert = d(0,x)$? Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: Would this satisfy $\left\lVert\lambda x\right\rVert=|\lambda|\left\lVert x \right\rVert$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a norm, the space $M$ must be a $\Bbb R$-vector space to begin with. Also, we want $\|cx\|=|c|\cdot\|x\|$, but in general $d(0,cx)\ne |c|d(0,x)$.

Comment: What does an ℝ-vector space? Is it just a vector space over the field ℝ? Just to confirm, you're saying that there is no axiom for metrics that gives it the linearity (well, sort of, but always positive) property of norms?

Comment: @MuchangBahng the standard metric on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ doesn't obey this homogeneity property. This metric is defined as $d(x,y)=\sum_n \frac{1}{2^n} \min(|x_n-y_n|,1)$.